# Handling Trailing Colon in YAML

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm using YAML::Tiny to write to and read from a file in Perl.  Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with data that ends with a colon:

```
my $test_message = {"hoody" => 'hoo:'};
my $dump = YAML::Tiny::Dump($test_message);
my $reloaded = YAML::Tiny::Load($dump);
print Data::Dumper::Dumper($reloaded);
```

This produces `Failed to load YAML document from string at [the line with YAML::Tiny::Load]`.

First off, this looks like a bug.  Is it?  Or am I expecting too much from YAML::Tiny?  (We're using YAML::Tiny 1.48; the newest is 1.50, which IT assures me will be installed soon.)

Second, is there any way to work around this?  I'm trying to use escape characters, but I must not be doing it right.  I tried replacing the colon with `\x3A`, but that doesn't give the desired behavior.  (Printing `$dump` gives the string back unchanged [`hoo\x3A`],
while the `Data::Dumper::Dumper` line makes it `'hoo\\x3A'`.)

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: This code is working for me on perl 5.12 and YAML::Tiny version 1.5.0

Comment: @ennuikiller:  Thanks.  I'll take that as confirmation that upgrading to 1.50 will make this go away.

Comment: Works for me with YAML. Sorry, I don't have YAML::Tiny installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug [was fixed in 1.5](https://metacpan.org/source/ADAMK/YAML-Tiny-1.50/Changes#L5)
You may consider using YAML instead of YAML::Tiny (Tiny version should have just the same interface as it's parent).

I think any workarounds will make things only worsen after you finally get YAML::Tiny 1.5 with bugfixes. I'd recommend you put `use YAML::Tiny 1.50` in your code or switch to YAML.

Comment: Sadly, YAML isn't an option due to performance reasons.  For what I'm using it for, YAML::Tiny is ~43 times faster.  (Yup, I clocked it.)  And it matters.  However, I'm very encouraged to hear the bug has been fixed.  I'll pester IT to expedite.

Comment: @Eric Storm:  No, I haven't.  YAML::Tiny is available, whereas getting YAML::XS installed everywhere it needs to be would be a bloody nuisance.  Doesn't mean it's not the right move, though.  Any idea how much of a performance improvement I should expect over Tiny?

Comment: @BlairHippo benchmark says that YAML::Tiny is about 3 times faster than YAML, but YAML::XS is about 4 times faster than YAML::Tiny (which means about 12 times faster than YAML!).
If you don't deploy to mac or shared hosting and care about performance it may be a good solution for you.